# Jquery Ajax Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form with 4 fields (ramo,garanzia,importo and destinazione) that ask to a Mysql db with this colums

ramo |garanzia|importo|destinazione|risultato|unita|

to estract "unita" for some combination of that 4 fields on form.

I want do this with a query using AJAX Jquery

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'find_result.php',
            //data: { ramo: ramo ,garanzia: garanzia,importo: importo ,destinazione: destinazione},
            data: $("#data_form").serialize(),
            dataType: "JSON",
            }).done(function(reply) {

            $.each(reply, function(key, value) {
                alert(unita.value);
            });
```

JSON result of find_result.php is

```
 [{"ramo":"bagaglio","garanzia":"Rimborso rifacimento documenti","importo":"Importo noto","destinazione":"Italia","risultato":"In caso di importo noto e limporto noto verificando che non superi il massimale previsto dalla garanzia. In caso affermativo la riserva e il massimale","unita":"0"}]
```

As u can see "unita" value exist and is 0 in Json.
So why alert(unita.value) doesn't work?? In chrome debug there's this error message

```
(index):156 Uncaught ReferenceError: unita is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> ((index):156)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.12.1.js:370)
    at Object.<anonymous> ((index):155)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.1.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.1.js:3362)
    at done (jquery-1.12.1.js:9836)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.12.1.js:10302)
```

Thx a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$.each(reply, function(key, value) {
  alert(value.unita);
});
```

```js
let result = [{"ramo":"bagaglio","garanzia":"Rimborso rifacimento documenti","importo":"Importo noto","destinazione":"Italia","risultato":"In caso di importo noto e limporto noto verificando che non superi il massimale previsto dalla garanzia. In caso affermativo la riserva e il massimale","unita":"0"}]

$.each(result, function(index, value) {
  console.log(value.unita);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow if i write "value.unita" works! Mmm why "unita.value" no? Ok I understand maybe because value is the object but so why instead for example (ramo.value) works? Maybe because is an input variable of ajax?

Comment: Because you're getting the `keys` from the `value`, so you were doing it upside down.

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(value.unita);`
you defined the object in your forloop as value.

Answer (score 0):

The var `unita` doesn't exist in your JS.

```
$.each(reply, function(key, item) {
    alert(item.unita.value);
});
```